# Is the word order grammatically correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is the word order in the following correct?

> Mass media representatives will be present for official coverage of the course of the conference

Comment: I don't immediately understand the meaning of the sentence, so the word order or the choice of words is therefore presumably incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify things a bit and change it to: "Mass media representatives will be present to cover the conference".

Also, by "of the course" I suppose you mean "over the course", which can be more eloquently summarized as "the entire".

You might then consider: "Mass media representatives will be present to officially cover the entire conference".

Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the word order is fine. And there is nothing incorrect about the sentence.

1. *Mass media representatives will be present [at the conference].*
2. They will be there for the *official coverage of the course of the conference*. They will be there to cover it in some official capacity.

The *course of the conference* refers to whatever transpires during the conference.

And yes, there are other ways to say the same thing or similar. But you asked about this sentence (dunno whether it is yours or one you read somewhere). If you really meant to ask about writing alternatives to such a sentence, say so. Other answers here seem to be trying to help with that. But this sentence is fine as is.